# Using a function for multiple files

Tags: python, file, numpy, pyfits

I have written a function that i need to use for multiple files. when I use it for one file it works but when i try to use it for more i get errors. I have attached my code, can anybody tell me what is wrong with it?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#peice of code to find the information from a star catalog for the brightest star from each indiviual CCD

import os, sys, glob, pyfits, numpy

dr='/home/desar2.cosmology.illinois.edu+7443/DESFiles/desardata/OPS/red/20130321211637_20130106/red/DECam_00166306/catalogs/'

def meanarr(image, res=None):
 "costruct code which runs over a single ccd to get the means"
 a=pyfits.getdata(image).MAG_AUTO
 q=numpy.mean(a)
 s=pyfits.getdata(image).X2WIN_IMAGE
 j=numpy.mean(s)
 f=pyfits.getdata(image).Y2WIN_IMAGE
 z=numpy.mean(f)
 g=pyfits.getdata(image).XYWIN_IMAGE
 h= numpy.mean(g)
 a=[q,j,z,h]
 print a
 s0=''
 return res

#image=dr+'DECam_00166306_01_star_catalog.fits'
#s=meanarr(image)

for arg in (sys.argv):
 print arg
 s=meanarr(arg)

print '---done---'
```

It should just print a list of four figures for each input files, but i think there is a problem in the last four lines.

Comment: Please use tags pertaining to your programming environment, such as `python` and `pyfits`, instead of overly generic ones such as `file` and `function`.

Comment: okay, next time I will.

Comment: The first element of `sys.argv` is always your script that you run, not the image. Could that be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element of sys.argv is always your script that you run, not the image. Could that be the error?

You should do

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print arg
    s=meanarr(arg)
```